# Process resource limit on Windows

Tags: c++, c, linux, windows

What are the alternative `setrlimit()` and `getrlimit()` on Windows?
I am looking for c or c++ alternatives.
Is there a 3rd party implementation for those function like boost?

I am more interested in limiting size of process virtual memory `RLIMIT_AS` and stack size `RLIMIT_STACK`

please note that `RLIMIT_AS` and `RLIMIT_STACK` are inputs to `setrlimit()` function

Comment: Considering that `RLIMIT_AS` affects `brk`, `mmap` and `mremap`, none of which exist on Windows, the question seems a bit hypothetical.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think there is no address space limitation in windows, but maybe you can build something [according this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778.aspx):

Regarding to Stack Limit, you can use `GetCurrentThreadStackLimits` and `SetThreadStackGuarantee`.